# Store value for a longer time - (how to store boolean value in cookie)

Tags: php, html, session, session-cookies

I know that by using `$_SESSION`, one can store values over time. The default time is 1440 seconds = 24 minutes. I would like my values to be stored: for a longer time/until the browser has been closed.

Let's say I want to store the a boolean value and string value. Is session the best way?

For example: `$_SESSION["value"] = true;` and `$_SESSION["value2"] = "my_string";`?

Is session the best way, or are there any other good/better solutions? The values has to be available for all the pages (.php) on my website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookies to store data for longer period of time.
so using cookies would be like

**Set Cookie**

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "value2";
$cookie_value = "my_string";
//Cookie to hold true false can set using 0 or 1 like 
//setcookie('value', '0'); 0 for false, 1 for true

setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>
```

**Retrieve Cookie value**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
     echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
     echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!";
     echo "Cookie Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
```

**Setting and retrieving cookie for boolean**

```
<?php
$CookieVar = true;

// setting the cookie
setcookie('myCookie', $CookieVar ? '1' : '0'); //set '1' if true else set '0'

if (isset($_COOKIE['myCookie']) AND $_COOKIE['myCookie'] === '1') {
    
    echo 'true';

} else {
    
    echo 'false';
}

?>
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Can you also show an example on how to set and retrieve a cookie value for true/fase?

Comment: But afaik, cookies isn't really safe? The users can create/change value to access website?

Comment: @Andrei If you are saving anything on client side it really isn't 100% safe. It can be tampered in a someway around

Answer (score 0):

You can use the local storage for saving the data and for using it from any page on the website.

Using Javascript

```
window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
```

This key can be removed using

```
window.localStorage.removeItem(key, value);
```

You can get the key value using

```
window.localStorage.getItem(key);
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but can't you just change the values in Dev tools(F12). And how long is this stored? Will it be removed when restarting browser?